# A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site. Please choose another title

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to make a REST api call and get the items in a document library using the below url

```
https://sitename.com/sites/sitecollectionname/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Policy%20&%20Procedure')/items
```

But I am getting the following error

> A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site. Please choose another title.

I checked for other lists, the REST api seems to work fine and returns items

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be incorrect, but looking at your code, I would change this:

```
Policy%20&%20Procedure
```

to this:

```
Policy%20%26%20Procedure
```

The unencoded & is probably what's causing the error.